# Is there a way to handle expensive computation of derived data in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm currently developing an application that performs large number of computation os front-end. These computations are part of mapStateToProps function that computes derived data from state.

I would like to compute derived data in WebWorker, but I'm not sure how to implement whole data flow. `reselect` could help a bit with rendering view for the second time, but it still doesn't solve the problem of blocking the UI during computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to pushing the computation into a web-worker; you can author a custom [Redux Middleware](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) to intercept an action; read any additional state from the store and then pass that off to your web-worker.  When the worker calls back your middleware can dispatch the result.

Bonus points for implementing a cache inside the middleware :)

**edit**: Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/tappleby/342754c4a3fe02d82ec0) which follows the same thought process.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. The gist is very helpful. I try to implement this or some other ideas and will post the results later.

Comment: Middleware is definitely the best solution. We tried few other solutions and it didn't work out that well.